# how to get an exact directory through os.walk in python

Tags: python, regex, if-statement, os.walk

I have a directory that contains directories like /sample1, /sample10, /sample11 etc.
when I am using `os.walk` to access all of them one by one, I am facing some difficulties.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(mypath):
    if 'sample1' in root:
       print root
```

now, this returns all root /sample1, /sample10, /sample11 etc. as 'sample1' is there for all directories. how can I obtain only sample1 directory ?

may be regex would be good but I dont know how to use it.

Comment: If you are at the very beginning with python, you should always study some elementary language features here: http://docs.python.org/library/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Test for equality: `if root == "sample1": …`

Comment: or `if root == '/sample1':` since he seems to have the directory prefix in his strings

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if this will help but i hope this answers your question:

using the 'os module' you can set more than a base file
the bottom explains it all if you understand this...

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath (__file__)
#meaning that it will locate the file your program is in
file = BASE_DIR + "\\file.format"
```

but, you can actually change this directory in a couple few ways

```
Files_folder = BASE_DIR + "\\foldername"
musicfls = Files_folder + "\\Audio"
spritefls = Files_folder + "\\sprites"
#and so on and on...
```

or even

```
sample1 = BASE_DIR + "\\directory name"
sample2 = BASE_DIR + "\\directoryname"
```

this means that if you want to find these directories, just make a base with all the directories you stored or compressed, and name them by `BASE_DIR + "\\path\dir"`

if this doesnt do anything, theres still 1 more solution:
you can seperate the directories into different file folders
then name your files in the directories...
and either

```
def sample1():...
```

or

```
exec("")/os.system["" or BASE_DIR + "\path"]

if this doesnt work i have no idea
```